# Install Modes Safely phpBB

Tags: forum, mode, phpbb, phpbb3

As a newbie with phpBB forum (3.1), I understand that modes may change data in forum database and files.

Therefore, I would like to backup the site before mode installation, so that the previous state could be easily restores in case it is necessary.

What are the exact instructions to install and de-install modes safely?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you mean 'Mods' instead of 'modes'?

phpBB v3.1.x does not use Mods like the old 3.0.x branch where core code needed to be changed. Instead it uses extensions which are uploaded to your server and simply activated in your ACP.

As a precaution it is always advised to back up your database before making any changes to your site.

Full instructions are on the phpBB sie here - https://www.phpbb.com/extensions/installing/